# The max length limit of a formula in excel

Tags: office-js

For our project Excel Javascript.

We have a problem for write into cell a formula with a text length > 256 characters.

how could we resolver this fix?

*=ZZZZZ.DATA("YYYYY";RAW;"03XXX.UCH03.060;03XXX.UCH03.061;03XXX.UCH03.218;03XXX.UCH03.221;03XXX.UCH03.222;03XXX.UCH03.232;03XXX.UCH03.259;03XXX.UCH03.275;03XXX.UCH03.303;03XXX.UCH03.321;03XXX.UCH03.326;03XXX.UCH03.365;03XXX.UCH03.474;03XXX.UCH03.891;03XXX.UCH03.985;03XXX.UCH03.C04;03XXX.UCH03.C06;03XXX.UCH03.C07";"ayer";"hoy";"1;2;3";"false";"false")*

Thanks

Comment: What if you input this formula directly via formula builder? Could you please share the error message? What's your current locale? are you running in Franch or Spain?

Comment: We are running in Spain. The error message "Falta el argumento, este no es válido o tiene un formato incorrecto."  this codeline app:  sheet.getRangeByIndexes(rowSelected, colSelected, 1, 1).values = formula;

Comment: From the error message, it looks like this formula missed some arguments or invalid format, instead of hitting a limitation. could you please double-check the formula?

Comment: Aparently el problem is that a text value of formula can`t be > 256 characters.   "03XXX.UCH03.060..." using the operator "&" it could works

Comment: there is a limitation is that each argument cannot be more than 255 characters. i am not sure what do you mean for using operator "&", could you verify whether characters of any of the argument is more than 255?